# Assign a role to multiple users with a command - discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot, and I want the bot run a command in a specific channel. For example, `y` role is given to a number of people. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Conditions:

> I want the bot run a command in a specific channel

- You'll need a condition checking whether the command is in the correct channel.

> "y" role is given to x people

- You'll need to iterate through a list of members.

Another criteria for this is that the bot's highest role is above any role it's attempting to assign.

---

### Code:

So with all this being said, let's write up a command to do it, assuming this isn't going to be in its separate cog:

```
import asyncio

from discord.ext import commands


def is_correct_channel(ctx):
    return ctx.channel.id == 112233445566778899


@commands.check(is_correct_channel)
@bot.command()
async def giverole(ctx, role: discord.Role, members: commands.Greedy[discord.Member]):
    for m in members:
        await m.add_roles(role)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)  # You don't want to get ratelimited!
    await ctx.send("Done!")
```

---

### Syntax:

`!giverole rolename @user#1234 998877665544332211 username`
It will take the role as the first argument (can be name, mention, or ID). The following arguments will be attempted to be converted to members.

Feel free to also add whatever error handling you wish to add. For example, the role may not have been found, or no members were given, etc.

---

### References:

- [`commands.check()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.check)
- [`TextChannel.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.id)
- [`discord.Role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role)
- [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member)
- [`commands.Greedy`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#greedy) - This will look through each argument, attempting to convert it to a member until it can no more.
- [`Member.add_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles) - Is a coroutine, therefore needs to be awaited.
- [`asyncio.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep) - Also a coroutine.
- [`Context.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.send)
- [Cog example](https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/d78c061a4798ae81be9825468fe146be) - Separating your bot into separate modules, both for organisation and greater control over functionality.